# Сохранить картинку с сервера IP камеры на компьютер

Tags: python, ip, kivy

У меня есть простенькая ip камера; и есть локальный сервер, на котором можно смотреть видео стрим с этой камеры (в моем случае адрес имеет такой вид: "http://192.168.43.99/").

Мне бы нужно было с помощью python3 сохранить текущее изображение с данного сервера (локально на компьютер).
Вот как выглядит html код данного сервера:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e;">
    <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;" src="http://192.168.43.99/">
</body>
```

А вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть у картинки src="http://192.168.43.99/"

Пробовал сохранить картинку с помощью этого кода:

```
import urllib.request as ur

ur.urlretrieve('http://192.168.43.99/', 'img.jpg')
```

Но картинка, к сожалению не сохраняется.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вообще, мне нужно в свое приложение (на kivy) выводить как раз видео поток; я думаю каждую секунду сохранять по 20-30 кадров, и выводить их в приложение. Может это плохая идея, и есть способы получше? Если знаете, то могли бы, пожалуйста, подсказать.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Код, который Вы привели, так выглядит после рендера (отработки всех `js`) страницы? Стоит приложить то, что вернёт `view-source:192.168.43.99`.

Comment: Используйте opencv. Это облегчит Вашу жизнь )

Comment: Ваша простенькая камера наверняка имеет свой api с помощью которого можно делать скриншоты. Поэтому не мучайтесь с сервером и opencv, а, для начала, почитайте про api камеры.

Comment: Дело в том, что я использую модуль esp32-cam, и прошивку для него писал я сам. Поэтому API нету такого, как хотелось бы.

Comment: А при попытке использовать `view-source:192.168.43.99` , страница бесконечно грузится (ничего не отображается).

Comment: Изменил, прошивку на esp32-cam и теперь отлично могу сохранять изображения. Спасибо всем за помощь.